# How to find TOP (1) and GROUP BY at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I'm currently trying to find the TOP(1) Number_of_Orders based on the different state. How would one go about doing that?

[image: SQL Table]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 2):

A version I like, which avoids an explicit subquery:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY state ORDER BY Number_of_Orders DESC);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY state ORDER BY number_of_orders DESC) r
  FROM t
)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE r = 1
```

Row number function establishes an incrementing counter starting at 1 that increases as number of orders decreases, and it restarts at 1 when state changes

If you want ties, use DENSE_RANK instead of row_number

Answer (score 0):

select state,max(Number_of_Orders) as [Top 1 Order]
from [yourtable]
group by state